# Python TCPServer

Tags: python, multithreading, tcpserver

I have a simple question.

When I create a python TCPServer for example using the example code :

```
import sys, SocketServer, os
from multiprocessing import Pool, Queue

class MyTCPHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
                # self.request is the TCP socket connected to the client
                self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
                print "{} wrote:".format(self.client_address[0])
                print self.data
                # just send back the same data, but upper-cased
                self.request.sendall(self.data.upper())


if __name__ == '__main__':

    pool = Pool(processes=2)

    HOST, PORT = "localhost", 9999
    server = SocketServer.TCPServer((HOST,PORT), MyTCPHandler )
    server.serve_forever()
```

My question is : How can i pass to the function handle on the Class MyTCPHandler the Object Pool ?

Thanks

Comment: you should consider a higher level library like twisted and spare the pain of dealing with plain sockets. You won't regret.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a multithreading `TCPServer` you can use the `ThreadingMixIn` mixin class like this:

```
import SocketServer

class ThreadedTCPServer(SocketServer.ThreadingMixIn, SocketServer.TCPServer):
    pass
```

You can also have a fork based TCPServer by using `ForkingMixIn` in the same way as before.

More info can be found in the [doc](http://docs.python.org/library/socketserver.html#asynchronous-mixins).

Comment: Yes, I want to have multithreading. But I want to control the threads generated. Any tips how can i do that ?

Comment: @JorgeMachado: You can check the code of ``ThreadingMixIn`` (http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/227a22288688/Lib/SocketServer.py#l579) and you can create your own Mixin like the one offered by standard library and use it instead.